# problems with subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess

The blow command works well in the shell/terminal, but something goes wrong when it is called in my python script using subprocess.call() method.

```
-- command in shell/terminal
$ th neural_style.lua -gpu 0 -style_image input/style.jpg -content_image input/img.jpg

-- subprocess.call() in python script
# this works
subprocess.call(["th", "neural_style.lua", "-gpu", "0"])
# this goes wrong - Error during read_image: Read Error
-- subprocess.call in the python script
subprocess.call(["th", "neural_style.lua", "-gpu", "0", "-style_image" "input/style.jpg" "-content_image" "input/img.jpg"])
```

How should I use subprocess.call ?

Comment: What is going wrong? Are you getting a specific error message?

Comment: subprocess.call(["th", "neural_style.lua", "-gpu", "0", "-style_image", "input/style.jpg", "-content_image", "input/img.jpg"])

Comment: Error during read_image: Read Error

Comment: what if you wrap it in a shell e.g. `subprocess.call(["bash", "-c", "th neural_style.lua -gpu 0 -style_image input/style.jpg -content_image input/img.jpg"])`

Comment: @JasonD what would that accomplish?

Comment: missing commas between `"-style_image" "input/style.jpg" "-content_image" "input/img.jpg"`

Comment: `["th", "neural_style.lua", "-gpu", "0", "-style_image" "input/style.jpg" "-content_image" "input/img.jpg"] == ['th', 'neural_style.lua', '-gpu', '0', '-style_imageinput/style.jpg-content_imageinput/img.jpg']` give a `True` value

Comment: @Skaperen good eye, that's surely the problem. Post an answer?

Comment: I was just wondering if some shell feature or variable isn't there in the subprocess call that is in your own terminal. That's all.

Answer (score -1):

As the error message says, it failed to read an image. The error is (presumably) coming from the `th` program you're calling. I'd guess that there's additional information in the error message you haven't shared, but the most likely explanation is that you're running your Python script from a different directory than where you're running `th` directly. For example are you running your Python script from an IDE? It's likely running commands relative to the workspace or project directory.

The first thing to try is swapping the image arguments for [absolute paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) (e.g. `/home/username/input.style.jpg` or wherever they're located). This will work around the scripts running from different directories.

Once you've verified that's the issue how you fix it is up to you. You could simply run your Python script from the correct directory, you could specify the paths relative to where your script runs, or you could simply always use absolute paths your Python script. Which you chose really depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for you advice, but the paths are right. I've got this problem through. Before the subprocess.call() was called in my script, I opened one of the image, input/img.jpg, but did not close it. So closing the file make it right.

Comment: @yangao Too bad you didn't include that in your question. If you don't provide all the details, or even better an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), people can only guess what your problem might be.